# What is simulated multiple inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I understand that Java does not have multiple inheritance.

I'm reading Effective Java 3rd Edition Item 20 (page 102), here is a portion from the page:

> The beauty of skeletal implementation classes is that they provide all of the
> implementation assistance of abstract classes without imposing the severe constraints that abstract classes impose when they serve as type definitions. For most
> implementors of an interface with a skeletal implementation class, extending this
> class is the obvious choice, but it is strictly optional. If a class cannot be made to
> extend the skeletal implementation, the class can always implement the interface
> directly. The class still benefits from any default methods present on the interface
> itself. **Furthermore, the skeletal implementation can still aid the implementor’s
> task. The class implementing the interface can forward invocations of interface
> methods to a contained instance of a *private inner class* that extends the skeletal
> implementation.** This technique, known as simulated multiple inheritance, is
> closely related to the wrapper class idiom discussed in Item 18. It provides many
> of the benefits of multiple inheritance, while avoiding the pitfalls.

Since English is not my native language, the bold part of the quote got me confused. And I got no result when search for the answer.

What is this `private inner class`? Is this like a normal inner class?

In practice, does this technique get use very often?

Any code example would be extremely useful for me to visualize!

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436995/why-and-when-to-use-skeletal-implementation-in-java). It may not answer your question, but is useful I guess.

Comment: @Zakk Thank you. But I already read it before I ask the question. Unfortunately, without an example, I still cannot visualize it correctly.

Comment: _"Is this like a normal inner class?"_ Yes, it is. I don't know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264730/16835308) answers your question.

Comment: @Zakk Thank you. I think I found the answer from [this useful article](https://10kloc.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/abstract-interfaces-the-mystery-revealed/). It has a nice example but never mentions **simulated multiple inheritance** but I guess that's acceptable.

Comment: So, please answer your own question and mark it as the accepted one. This way, others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this private inner class?

- `private` is [access modifier in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).
- `inner` means that class is placed\nested in another class

An example:

```
class OuterClass {
    private class InnerClass {
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the `private inner class` now but my main question is about `simulated multiple inheritance`. Any concrete code example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have an interface called **`Shape`** that represents geometric shapes with methods for calculating area and perimeter.

We will create a skeletal implementation class **`AbstractShape`** that provides default implementations for these methods, and then we will have a class **`Circle`** that directly implements the **`Shape`** interface but also reuses code from AbstractShape by forwarding method calls to an inner class.

```
// Interface representing a geometric shape
interface Shape {
    double getArea();
    double getPerimeter();
}

// Skeletal implementation class providing default implementations
abstract class AbstractShape implements Shape {
    // Common method implementations for all shapes
    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return 0.0;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 0.0;
    }
}

// Class representing a Circle, which directly implements Shape
class Circle implements Shape {
    private final double radius;

    // Constructor for Circle
    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    // Inner class that extends the skeletal implementation
    private class CircleImpl extends AbstractShape {
        @Override
        public double getArea() {
            return Math.PI * radius * radius;
        }

        @Override
        public double getPerimeter() {
            return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
        }
    }

    // Forward method calls to the inner CircleImpl instance
    private final CircleImpl circleImpl = new CircleImpl();

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return circleImpl.getArea();
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return circleImpl.getPerimeter();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape circle = new Circle(5.0);
        System.out.println("Circle Area: " + circle.getArea());
        System.out.println("Circle Perimeter: " + circle.getPerimeter());
    }
}
```

In this example, **`AbstractShape`** serves as a skeletal implementation of the **`Shape`** interface, providing default implementations for `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()`. The **`Circle`** class directly implements the **`Shape`** interface, but it also has an inner class **`CircleImpl`**, which extends **`AbstractShape`** and provides specific implementations for `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()` tailored to circles.

By forwarding the method calls to the inner **`CircleImpl`** instance, the **`Circle`** class is effectively reusing the code from **`AbstractShape`** without having to extend it directly.

This allows the **`Circle`** class to benefit from the implementation assistance provided by the skeletal implementation, while still being free to implement other interfaces or extend different classes as needed.

This is what is referred to as *simulated multiple inheritance* in Java and as you can see it's way more flexible than using only polymorphism and inheritance.